# Adding an ArrayList as a column in excel using java

Tags: java, excel

I have two ArrayLists named **ID** and **Name**.

```
ID: [1, 2, 3, 4]
Name: ["X", "Y", "Z", "A"]
```

I want to write them in an excel file in two distinct columns:

```
ID      Name
1        X
2        Y
3        Z
4        A
```

How can I do it? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: use apache poi https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/index.html

Answer (score 1):

#### Use CSV structure and parse it in Excel

Assuming that your two arrays have the exact number of elements, you can iterate through the first one and export in a **C**omma **S**eparated **V**alue file which will then be parsed in Excel.

```
List<String> ID = new ArrayList<>() {{
    add("1");
    add("2");
    add("3")
    add("4");
}};
List<String> Name = new ArrayList<>() {{
    add("X");
    add("Y");
    add("Z");
    add("A");
}};

PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("csvFile.csv", "UTF-8");
boolean firstLine = true;
int i = 0;

for(String id : ID) {
    if(firstLine) {
        writer.println("ID,Name");
        firstLine = false;
    }
    writer.println(id + "," + Name.get(i));
    i++;
}
writer.close();
```

After the execution, you'll end up with this file:

```
ID,Name
1,X
2,Y
3,Y
4,A
```

which you can parse in Excel and split it using `,` as a delimiter.

Comment: I would be grateful if you added a comment on why you downvoted my answer; unless of course there's a downvote bounty going on.